# Why are multiple numbers not workin in IN clause for DB2 z/OS

Tags: sql, db2-zos

So I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM SOMESCHEMA.SOMETABLE
WHERE ID IN (123);
```

Which does work as intended.

But

```
SELECT * FROM SOMESCHEMA.SOMETABLE
WHERE ID IN (123,456);
```

Does not work!

But "funny":

```
SELECT * FROM SOMESCHEMA.SOMETABLE
WHERE ID IN ('123','456');
```

Does return both entries I expected?

Why is that? And who had this great idea?!

ID is:

- TYPE_NAME: `BIGINT`
- COLUMN_SIZE: `19`

Comment: Try `WHERE ID IN (123, 456);`. (I.e. a space after comma.) If the comma in `123,456` is interpreted as a decimal comma...

Comment: You are right! But why? The , character should always be handled like a delimiter not a float point....

Comment: Perhaps a locale/regional setting?

Comment: Code is written in "english" and should always be. So I think this is a bug

Comment: It's a setting, you can chose point or comma.